# How to use doctrine in my EntityType form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

```
class AnalisiType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        if($options['data']->getIdProprietario()==NULL){
            $data_proprietario='';
        }else{
            $data_proprietario=$options['data']->getIdProprietario();
        }
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $builder   ->add('idProprietario', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => false,

                'placeholder' => 'Seleziona Anagrafica se presente',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:anagrafica',
                'query_builder' => function (anagraficaRepository $er ) {

                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.idTipologia = 1');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'ragione_sociale',
                        'data'=>$em->getReference("AppBundle:anagrafica",$options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getId())    ,

                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'chosen-select'
                ),
            ))
```

MY goal is in edit form set tha default data . Searching in forum i find that

'data'=>$em->getReference("AppBundle:anagrafica",$options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getId())    ,

is the correct syntax but i don't understand how to use doctrine in form .
This form always give me error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "AppBundle\Form\AnalisiType"
```

i need to add use ??????

My only solution is create a service??

my services.yml

## Learn more about services, parameters and containers at

## http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

```
services:
    #service_name:
    #    class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
    #    arguments: ['@another_service_name', 'plain_value', '%parameter_name%']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Symfony 2.8 you have to define your form as service and inject EntityManger:

```
services:
    form:
        class: YourBundle\Form\Type\YourType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

if you are on Symfony 3.3 your form is already a service and you can just typehint EntityManagerInterface in your construct:

```
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

also be sure that you have enabled autoconfigure in 3.3 or you will have to register your form as service:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository}'

    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: Thank's for help .. i have symfony 3.3 but now i have this error  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\AnalisiType::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface,   and i have added      use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\AnalisiType::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\richiesta_analisi\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php on line 85 and defined

Comment: do you use autoconfigure? can you link me your service.yml?

Comment: # Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    #service_name:
    #    class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
    #    arguments: ['@another_service_name', 'plain_value', '%parameter_name%']

Comment: @FrancescoArreghini I edited my answer with my `service.yml` and maybe take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Comment: thank's .. i try always that serveces.yml but  now other error:  A "tags" entry must be an array for service "AppBundle\Controller\" in C:\xampp\htdocs\richiesta_analisi\app/config\services.yml. Check your YAML syntax.

Comment: @FrancescoArreghini I fixed service.yml, you can now copy that part again, you will see the paths are a little different

Comment: thank 's to help but same error FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 118:
A "tags" entry must be an array for service "AppBundle\Controller\" in C:\xampp\htdocs\richiesta_analisi\app/config\services.yml. Check your YAML syntax in C:\xampp\htdocs\richiesta_analisi\app/config\services.yml (which is being imported from "C:\xampp\htdocs\richiesta_analisi\app/config\config.yml").

Comment: @FrancescoArreghini are you sure you are using Symfony 3.3 version?

Comment: sorry too much ... i see 3.2.13 version  ... i follow this tutorial step 2  http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/form/form_dependencies.html  but whe i try to use $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();  always said me Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "AppBundle\Form\AnalisiType".

Comment: @FrancescoArreghini do it like this http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service , and inject it as service and in your constructor you already get $entityManager, you don't ened to call `$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();`

Comment: sorry ,maybe i'm the problem but in   my controller i have   $analisi = new Analisi();
        $form = $this->createForm(AnalisiType::class, $analisi);
        $form->handleRequest($request);     and my goal id use 'data'=>$em->getReference("AppBundle:anagrafica",$options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getId())    , anagrafica is another entity

Comment: @FrancescoArreghini you have to register your form as a service, check first part of my answer for Symfony 2.8, that solution is for Symfony < 3.3